# why here in the class the loop retunrs the index with 0 not the 0,1,2,3...etc?

Tags: python, oop

```
class test:
    def __init__(self,name,debartment,section,salary,bounus,age,rating):
        self.name = name
        self.debartment = debartment
        self.section = section
        self.salary = salary
        self.age = age
        self.bounus = bounus
        self.rating = rating
    def getInfo(self):
        info = [
            f"name => {self.name}",
            f"debartment => {self.debartment}",
            f"section => {self.section}",
            f"salary => {self.salary}",
            f"age => {self.age}",
        ]
        if self.age >= 40:

            self.bounus += 500
        else:

            self.bounus = 0
        info.append(f"bounus => {self.bounus}")

        if self.rating >= 3:

            self.rating = "exllent"
        else:

            self.rating = "not exllent"

        info.append(f"rating => {self.rating}")

        for i in range(len(info)):
            
            #return the info list elements

            return info[i]
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method call ends with the first return - so it only returns the name (element 0).

If you want to return every element, the following code worked for me:
delete the for loop with the return and replace it with the following line

```
return info
```

When you call it with

```
testinstance = test("name","department","section",40000,3000,40,3)
result = testinstance.getInfo()
print(result)
```

you will get the whole list:

```
['name => name', 'debartment => department', 'section => section', 'salary => 40000', 'age => 40', 'bounus => 3500', 'rating => exllent']
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `return` causes it to stop the loop and return the value from the method.

Try:

```
return [info[i] for i in range(len(info))]
```

Or more simply:

```
return info
```